# ¿"Septiembre" or "setiembre"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, deletreo

`Setiembre` is only used in Peru, AFAIK, but I wonder if there are any other countries where `setiembre`, as opposed to `septiembre`, is also valid.

RAE links the definition of `setiembre` to the definition of `septiembre` but offers no further details as to whether `setiembre` has always been a valid word or whether it's only used in Peru.

Comment: Well firstly, the names of months are not capitalized in Spanish, unlike English. So the choice is between "septiembre" or "setiembre".

Comment: Aguante setiembre!
Acá siempre se usó en no soy peruano.
Soy uruguayo...
Que venga setiembre bo!

Comment: En Uruguay tambien se usa Setiembre en lugar de Septiembre.

Comment: Curioso...primera vez que veo setiembre, todos los dias se aprende algo

Comment: Before any who are unsure of their Spanish start thinking that saying "setiembre" is vulgar (in the English sense) and wonder what on earth it might mean, note that the "translator" fell into the clutches of a false friend. He should have said "common".

Comment: **Catalan = Setembre
Castilian = Septiembre**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Septiembre's entry](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=septiembre) on *Diccionario Panhispánico de dudas* says both forms are valid, but the preferred one is Septiembre:

> (...) pero en el uso culto se prefiere decididamente la forma etimológica **septiembre**.

Comment: As a side note, I myself prefer to keep the "p" as in _séptimo_ (seventh), since it comes from latin _septimus_ (although now it is not anymore the seventh month of the year but the ninth).

Answer (score 4):

Me gustaría añadir algo más. A pesar de que `Setiembre` está aceptado por la RAE, en España (al menos en la región de Valencia) se considera el uso de `Setiembre` como vulgar y a menudo se hacen bromas sobre este término desde que la RAE lo incluyó.

I'd like to add something else. Althought `Setiembre` is accepted by the RAE, in Spain (at least in the Valencia area) it's considered that `Setiembre` is really vulgar and there are many jokes about this term since the RAE appended it.

Comment: It may be related with the fact that in Catalan they say `Setembre`, so it can be a sign of using the Catalan form instead of the Spanish one.

Answer (score 3):

In Uruguay "setiembre" is more used than "septimbre". Even calendars and street names are written "setiembre".

Answer (score 2):

"Setiembre" is valid everywhere, recently RAE made valid lots of eliminations of hard-to-pronounce double consonants (sétimo for séptimo, sicología instead of psicología, but funnily enough, psique cannot be written as sique).

Comment: I've been hearing "setiembre" for as long as I can remember on Peruvian TV. I sort of even recall reading a Mario Vargas Llosa article in El País using it as well. Jaime Baily -a well known TV figure and (mediocre) writer- definitely uses it. I wonder when RAE will start accepting "dotor" (doctor), "helicótero"(helicóptero), etc. which is rather common amongst people with low scholarity. "Haiga" -instead of haya- and "encandelillar" -instead of encandilar- are apparently also accepted.

Comment: +1 to Icarus for "dotor" and "helicótero" :)

Comment: Bayly is far from being a mediocre writer.

Comment: @Icarus: RAE accepts the relaxation of some sounds when speaking, but writing is a different thing. So you can relax the *p* before another consonant, but in writing it is still *helicóptero*, *concepto* and the like. When a generalization of the written form is observed, then RAE tends to accept it, though still preferring the original form. And, by the way, *haiga* instead of *haya* is not accepted at all.

Answer (score 1):

In Argentina, `Setiembre` is accepted, but `Septiembre` is far more popular.

Answer (score -1):

In **Costa Rica** we use `Setiembre` and `Septiembre` as well.