# What is the preferred used word for "subscripción"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, deletreo

- What is the preferred used word for "**subscripción**",
  "**[subscripción](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=subscripci%C3%B3n)**" or "**[suscripción](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=suscripci%C3%B3n)**"?
- Why are there two ways to write the same word?
- Are there any other words like this one where the "**b**" can be
  ommited? In what cases is it allowed?

Another example is **[substancia](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=substancia)/[sustancia](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sustancia)**.

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1099/12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, the correct form was *subscripción*; however, over the years, the relaxation of the sound of the *b* in the consonantic group *bs+consonant* led to the simplification in the writing of *bs+consonant* to *s+consonant*. Both spellings are still used (the RAE lists both spellings as valid), but nowadays the simplified form is the one that is almost exclusively preferred. Some other examples of this simplification are:

> *obscuro* -> *oscuro*.
>
> *subscribir* -> *suscribir*.
>
> *substancia* -> *sustancia*.
>
> *substitución* -> *sustitución*.
>
> *substraer -> *sustraer*.

There are cases in which this simplification shouldn't be used:

> *obstante*, cannot be simplified to *ostante*.
>
> *abstemio* cannot be simplified to *astemio*.

Of course, the group *bs+vowel* cannot be simplified to *s+vowel*, so it's not correct to write, for example, *osesivo* instead of *obsesivo*.